# How to bind a column in laravel Builder?

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code(Laravel 5.6 PHP 7.0):

```
$orders = DB::table('orders')
            ->selectRaw('?', ['id'])
            ->get();
```

In my imagination that code has to perform such sql:

```
SELECT `id` FROM orders
```

and has to return a result like:

```
array [
   0 => {
     "id": "1"
   }
   1 => {
     "id": "2"
   }
```

unfortunately it returns this:

```
array [
   0 => {
     "?": "id"
   }
   1 => {
     "?": "id"
   }
```

But if I run the following code everything works as I want:

```
$orders = DB::table('orders')
             ->selectRaw('id')
             ->get();
```

So, my questions are:

1. Why does the first code returns such a strange result?
2. How to bind a column?

Comment: Why use a raw query at all? `DB::table('orders')->select(['id'])->get()` does exactly what you want. Although it may not be really secure if you use user input to dynamically select columns (see password or access token columns).

Comment: @Namoshek It's just a simplified situation to get answers for my questions, not more

Comment: Well, as I answered, in your simplified situation, performing a normal select works perfectly fine. So maybe you try that or you give us the real thing to solve. :)

Comment: @Namoshek look at questions at the bottom of the post. You answered not my questions

Comment: You are right, I did not answer it directly. Hence the comment. But between the lines I tried to tell you that is isn't possible. PDO does not allow column and table names to be dynamically bound (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter)).

Comment: Its because PDO wraps bound paramters in quotes, so you're SQL would actually be something like `SELECT 'id' FROM orders`. You're selecting the string `id`, not the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because PDO wraps bound parameters in quotes, so you're SQL would actually be something like:

```
SELECT 'id' FROM orders
```

You're selecting the string id, not the column. You cannot bind column names, only values.

To get your query to work, in the same format as what you want, you'd need to do this:

```
$columns = ['id'];

$orders = DB::table('orders')
        ->select($columns)
        ->get();
```

If you want to be safer, for example, if you get the column names from a querystring or something, you can do:

```
$allowedColumns = ['id', 'product_name', 'some_other_field'];
$columns = array_only($request->get('columns'), $allowedColumns);

$orders = DB::table('orders')
        ->select($columns)
        ->get();
```

If you ever need to have a look at the raw SQL Laravel is generating, and the bound paramters, you can do the following:

```
$query = DB::table('table_name')->select(['id', 'column1']);

dd($query->toSql(), $query->getBindings());
```

Comment: Thanks. But I assume we need to use ''select'' method instead "selectRaw" in this case

Comment: Sorry, you're right, you'd need to use `select` instead of `selectRaw`. Although, you can still use `selectRaw` if you really need to by imploding the `$columns` array: `implode(', ', $columns);`